# How do I color a region enclosed by a curve drawn using tkz-euclide?

Tags: paths, tkz-euclide

I have a region enclosed by a closed curve as can been on the picture below.  How can I color this region?

I remark that I have used `tkz-euclide`, though I think the library `tikz-avoidpath` was created for drawing such figures for complex analysis, including filling with color, but couldn't figure it out how to use it mostly because of the  `neck` feature.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\definecolor{lgray}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \tikzset{tkz arrows/.style= 
    {postaction=
      {on each path=
        {tkz arrow=
          {Stealth[scale=1.5,black]}}}},  
    tkz smallarrows/.style= 
    {postaction=
      {on each path={tkz arrow=
          {Stealth[scale=1,black]}}}},
    tkz revsmallarrows/.style= 
    {postaction=
      {on each path={tkz arrow=
          {Stealth[scale=-1,black]}}}}}
  
  \draw[help lines, lgray] (-4,-1) grid (4,4);
  
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 3/0/R, -3/0/-R, -1.5/0/L_R, 0/3/H_R}
  % First 8th root of unity
  \tkzDefPoint(45:1){z_1}
  % c_1 will be the circle around z_1
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_1](0,.4){c_1}
  % Lines to find intersections with c_1
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_1](.05,0){r1}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_1](-.05,0){l1}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto -R--R](z_1)
  \tkzGetPoint{Z1}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Z1](.05,0){R1}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Z1](-.05,0){L1}
  % Intersection with c_1
  \tkzInterLC(r1,R1)(z_1,c_1) \tkzGetPoints{cr1}{sr1}
  \tkzInterLC(l1,L1)(z_1,c_1) \tkzGetPoints{sl1}{cl1}
  
  % Third 8th root of unity
  \tkzDefPoint(135:1){z_2}
  % c_2 will be the circle around z_2
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_2](0,.4){c_2}
  % Lines to find intersections with c_2
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_2](.05,0){r2}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_2](-.05,0){l2}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto -R--R](z_2)
  \tkzGetPoint{Z2}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Z2](.05,0){R2}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Z2](-.05,0){L2}
  % Intersection with c_2
  \tkzInterLC(r2,R2)(z_2,c_2) \tkzGetPoints{cr2}{sr2}
  \tkzInterLC(l2,L2)(z_2,c_2) \tkzGetPoints{sl2}{cl2}
  
  \tkzDrawPoints(z_1,z_2,-R,R,O)

  \tkzLabelPoints[above](H_R,L_R,c_1,c_2)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](-R,R)
  \tkzLabelPoint[below](O){$0$}
  \tkzLabelPoints[right](z_1)
  \tkzLabelPoints[left](z_2)
 
  % Draw L_R
  \tkzDrawSegments[tkz arrows](-R,L2 R2,L1 R1,R)
  \tkzDrawArc[tkz arrows,black](O,R)(-R)

  % Draw c_1 and c_2
  
  \tkzDrawArc[tkz revsmallarrows, black](z_1,cr1)(cl1)
  \tkzDrawArc[tkz revsmallarrows, black](z_2,cr2)(cl2)

  % Draw necks
  \tkzDrawSegment[ tkz smallarrows](cr1,R1)
  \tkzDrawSegment[tkz smallarrows](L1,cl1)
  \tkzDrawSegment[ tkz smallarrows](cr2,R2)
  \tkzDrawSegment[tkz smallarrows](L2,cl2)
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The main issue is that your closed curve isn't one, actually, since you drew it with multiple commands. If only it was drawn in one line of code, it would have been simple to fill it in. Maybe you could recreate the whole path into one line of command, fill it, then draw your arrowed lines upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tkz-euclide` is a tool for making Euclidean geometry figures so it is not especially suitable for doing anything else. Sometimes you have to find tricks to get certain results. SebGlav's comment is correct, one of the major problems of `tkz-euclide` is the loss of the global notion of `path`. Complex figures are formed by a juxtaposition of `paths`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\definecolor{lgray}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \tikzset{tkz arrows/.style= 
    {postaction=
      {on each path=
        {tkz arrow=
          {Stealth[scale=1.5,black]}}}},  
    tkz smallarrows/.style= 
    {postaction=
      {on each path={tkz arrow=
          {Stealth[scale=1,black]}}}},
    tkz revsmallarrows/.style= 
    {postaction=
      {on each path={tkz arrow=
          {Stealth[scale=-1,black]}}}}}
  
  \draw[help lines, lgray] (-4,-1) grid (4,4);
  
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 3/0/R, -3/0/-R, -1.5/0/L_R, 0/3/H_R}
  % First 8th root of unity
  \tkzDefPoint(45:1){z_1}
  % c_1 will be the circle around z_1
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_1](0,.4){c_1}
  % Lines to find intersections with c_1
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_1](.05,0){r1}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_1](-.05,0){l1}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto -R--R](z_1)
  \tkzGetPoint{Z1}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Z1](.05,0){R1}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Z1](-.05,0){L1}
  % Intersection with c_1
  \tkzInterLC(r1,R1)(z_1,c_1) \tkzGetPoints{cr1}{sr1}
  \tkzInterLC(l1,L1)(z_1,c_1) \tkzGetPoints{sl1}{cl1}
  
  % Third 8th root of unity
  \tkzDefPoint(135:1){z_2}
  % c_2 will be the circle around z_2
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_2](0,.4){c_2}
  % Lines to find intersections with c_2
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_2](.05,0){r2}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[z_2](-.05,0){l2}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto -R--R](z_2)
  \tkzGetPoint{Z2}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Z2](.05,0){R2}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Z2](-.05,0){L2}
  % Intersection with c_2
  \tkzInterLC(r2,R2)(z_2,c_2) \tkzGetPoints{cr2}{sr2}
  \tkzInterLC(l2,L2)(z_2,c_2) \tkzGetPoints{sl2}{cl2}
  
  \tkzDrawPoints(z_1,z_2,-R,R,O)

  \tkzLabelPoints[above](H_R,L_R,c_1,c_2)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](-R,R)
  \tkzLabelPoint[below](O){$0$}
  \tkzLabelPoints[right](z_1)
  \tkzLabelPoints[left](z_2)
  \begin{scope}
    \tkzClipCircle[out](z_1,cr1)
    \tkzClipCircle[out](z_2,cr2)
    \tkzClipPolygon[out](L1,R1,cr1,cl1)
    \tkzClipPolygon[out](L2,R2,cr2,cl2)
    \tkzDrawArc[tkz arrows,black,fill=teal!10](O,R)(-R)
  \end{scope}

  % Draw L_R
  \tkzDrawSegments[tkz arrows](-R,L2 R2,L1 R1,R)
  \tkzDrawArc[tkz arrows,black](O,R)(-R)

  % Draw c_1 and c_2
  
  \tkzDrawArc[tkz revsmallarrows, black](z_1,cr1)(cl1)
  \tkzDrawArc[tkz revsmallarrows, black](z_2,cr2)(cl2)

  % Draw necks
  \tkzDrawSegment[ tkz smallarrows](cr1,R1)
  \tkzDrawSegment[tkz smallarrows](L1,cl1)
  \tkzDrawSegment[ tkz smallarrows](cr2,R2)
  \tkzDrawSegment[tkz smallarrows](L2,cl2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh great, I forgot about the *clip out* option you provided in `tkz-euclide`, Alain. That was easy, after all. +1

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying, this is nevertheless what I needed.  The only thing is that the labels `c_1, c_2` are missing in the final product, but moving the `scope` environment before the labelling takes care of this.

Comment: @MátéWierdl Yes you are right about the labels. I used a `scope` to make it possible to place them but I forgot to do it.